# what setting causes catalina.out to be renamed as catalina.out.1

Tags: linux, tomcat, ubuntu-12.04

in my Linux server(ubuntu) the tomcat log file catalina.out is automatically rename to new file name eg. catalina.out catalina.out.1 , catalina.out.2 , catalina.out.3 , catalina.out.4  etc etc

so  what setting causes catalina out to be renamed as catalina.out.1 ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The default Tomcat 7 package in Ubuntu 12.04 installs the file `/etc/logrotate.d/tomcat7` which contains the logrotate config for catalina.out (I assume it is the same for Tomcat 6):

```
/var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out {
  copytruncate
  weekly
  rotate 52
  compress
  missingok
  create 640 tomcat7 adm
}
```

Type `man logrotate` on the command-line for more info.

Comment: yes your info is right but how to solve this issue as i said in my question?

Comment: `root@lbtest:/etc/logrotate.d# vi tomcat6
/var/log/tomcat6/catalina.out {
  copytruncate
  weekly
  rotate 52
  compress
  missingok
  create 640 tomcat6 adm
}`
so it should rotate weekly.. but it looks like it is rotating daily.. hw to solve this

Comment: Files should rotate weekly (that's what happens in my Ubuntu server). If they rotate daily and are named without the .gz extension, then something else must be going on. I don't see what can be causing this, sorry.

Comment: there is some other script or cron job running...  there was previously an admin who setup this box... looks like he put some scripts somewhere..  Can you suggest me what should i do?

Comment: You can check the cron scripts under the directories `/etc/cron.*`. I can't really help you without having more information. Are the timestamps of the log files showing a specific pattern? Can you show the output of `ls -l catalina.out*` (to see the timestamps)?